# Changing the word of a number to digit

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a series with the following kind of data:

[image]

I have extracted this smaller subset from a column containing a much larger string.
I want to convert wherever the word of a number is displayed to digit, for example:
"two" should become 2.

I've tried using the following code:

```
help_dict = {
    'one': '1',
    'two': '2',
    'three': '3',
    'four': '4',
    'five': '5',
    'six': '6',
    'seven': '7',
    'eight': '8',
    'nine': '9',
    'zero': '0'
}


years_of_exp.replace(help_dict, regex=True)
```

but it is not applying any such changes and returns the exact same output.

Comment: It seems like a small issue, is this for a pandas dataframe? Please post a small code example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running that line of code then you need to either use `inplace=True` or, overwrite the pandas Series for the changes to affect the former variable:

```
years_of_exp = years_of_exp.replace(help_dict,regex=True)
```

Or, but don't use them exclusively:

```
years_of_exp.replace(help_dict,regex=True,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Earlier I tried converting it to a dataframe and using inplace parameter but it wasn't applying any changes. Forgot to put it when trying with series. Thank you.